# Android build automation with svn using Hudson and Antscript

Tags: android

i downloaded the Hudson server for the windows and i used **java -jar hudson.war** and server started successfully by hitting **http://localhost:8080** once the console got opened i configured path of java and ant script mannually, now the problem is i dono how to write my ant script onto the console of hudson

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write ant script in hudson console. Your ant script would be a part of your repositories, and when you configure your jobs, you ask hudson to checkout your repo, and then run an ant task.

Then hudson would look for a build.xml file in your repository, and would launch that.

Comment: yeah but as per ur tutorial(http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/search/label/Ant) we need to run custom parameters like password from keystore these need to included in build.xml as <property file="passwords.properties"/> rite? how to automated these files that my question is

Comment: Those are simple properties files, that you would again put in your repositories.

Comment: am getting this following error when i build it on hudson **Target "ant" does not exist in the project "MainActivity"**

Comment: when i created a bat file saying **ant release** hudson server builds successfully, if i use the same command inside Invoke Ant am getting the following error **Target "ant" does not exist in the project "MainActivity"** how to fix this

Comment: Why would you create a bat file called ant release?

Comment: sorry i created a bat as **newAnt.bat** which has the command **ant release** in it, if i invoke this bat file on hudson console build id getting succed, but i would like to know why on invoke ant on hudson console am getting the error as i said rearlier